# Pluggable function and activation check?

Tags: plugins, activation, wp-mail

Plugin is defining pluggable `wp_mail()` function. My idea was to check if function is defined already and throw warning if other plugin beat me to it.

However this warning causes issues on activation. As far as I understand during normal operation plugin is loaded **before** `pluggable.php` but for the purpose of activation check it is loaded **after** pluggables.

What would be the robust/proper/suggested way to implement such check for pluggable function? There is no obvious (for me) way to distinguish activation and handle it separately.

Comment: isn't "function_exists()" good enough ?

Comment: @Bainternet on activation `pluggables.php` had already been processed and `wp_mail()` always exists.

Comment: @Rarst then i guess I'm missing the point here.

Comment: @Bainternet the point is that load order is different on activation and I don't see a robust way to handle that. I cannot implement check for environment I need if environment is not the same because of different load order.

Comment: @Rarst thanks for explaining, then in that case i have no idea.

Comment: Don't check on activation, instead check when the plugin is running(when the load order is correct) and use a function_exists check to set a flag, if the flag is set don't load plugin components and output a warning(or whatver) to the user so they know the plugin has activated but found a problem?

Comment: @t31os _Don't check on activation_ - as per question I don't know how to distinguish activation from normal operation.

Comment: Would checking if the `plugins_loaded` action has occured work? (i'm not testing, just thinking out loud)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do the check on activation?

Seriously, the best way I can think of is not to check for this on activation, but only in the normal plugin load process. And instead of throwing a warning (I assume you mean a PHP E_WARNING), perhaps putting an admin error box up would make more sense.

Comment: Still same sub-question - how do I know it is activation? The idea to check for `plugins_loaded` fired might work, but had not tested yet. Warning was more of a debug thing. Overall I no longer think this makes much sense to mess with in my case, but still interested in technical side.

Comment: A plugin should never really do anything just by being included. Everything should be put in a function that is hooked somewhere. plugins_loaded isn't run on the activation include, so any actual checks you want to do at "load" time should be hooked there.

Comment: please see context - `plugins_loaded` fires after loading pluggable stuff. It is useless for check if specific pluggable function is available and useless for defining such function. I don't see another way of timing defining pluggable function other than on include.

Comment: You can do checks on include, sure, but you need to defer taking actions on the results of those checks until at least plugins_loaded. In other words, you can check for a function's existence at include time, but you need to wait until at least plugins_loaded before doing anything like throwing up a warning or something.